# XPATH to extract data from CarWale.com?

Tags: xpath, extract

With help from a friend I made a script to extract all specs and features from pages like http://www.carwale.com/mercedesbenz-cars/e-class/e63amg-3049/
, it works but not perfectly.

He told me to use XPath `//tr[contains (.,"FEATURE NAME")]/td[2]`, but one of them is impossible to pick, using `//tr[contains (.,"Display")]/td[2]` it extract 4 features containing word `Display`. Is there any way to pick only the one labelled exactly Display?

```
<td>Trip Meter</td><td>Multi-Function Display </td>
<td>Heads Up Display (HUD)</td><td>No </td>
<td>Display</td><td>LCD Display </td>
<td>Display Screen for Rear Passengers</td><td>No </td>
```

I also extracted car color names using XPath `//div[@class='colorName']`

I want also car color RGB values, or whole style code and remove unneeded code using find/replace, what XPath I need?

```
<div class="colours" style="background-color: #040404; height: 30px; width: 130px; margin: 7px"></div>
```

Comment: To get sibling 'td' tags which contain display to a 'td' tag which contains display, you can do `//tr/td[contains(.,'Display')]/following-sibling::td[contains(.,'Display')]`

Comment: Nothing is extracted, [INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION], I am still waiting for someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Extract 'td' tag containing 'Display' if it's preceding sibling contains 'Display':

```
//tr/td[contains(.,'Display')]/following-sibling::td[contains(.,'Display')]
```

Extract RGB hex string:

```
//div/substring-before(substring-after(@style,'background-color: '),';')
```

Comment: XPath Helper extension in Chrome says [INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION] at RGB one and [NULL] at other one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XPath helper, i've tested these examples with http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath (XPath 2.0 selected) against the HTML content from http://www.carwale.com/mercedesbenz-cars/e-class/e63amg-3049/